# How to access the HR schema objects through a user defined procedure in Oracle 18c?

Tags: oracle, plsql, procedure

I have given the code and the error messages I got when I try to create a procedure being *user1*. I try to access employees table in the sample hr schema in Oracle XE 18c. Can I know how to access hr schema objects via a user defined procedures

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE proc_1 IS
v_name hr.employees.first_name%TYPE;
v_num NUMBER;
BEGIN
SELECT first_name INTO v_name FROM hr.employees
WHERE employee_id=100;
v_num:=5;
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('test'||v_name);
DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(v_num);
END;
 /
```

Warning: Procedure created with compilation errors.

```
SQL> show errors
Errors for PROCEDURE PROC_1:

LINE/COL ERROR
-------- -----------------------------------------------------------------
2/8      PL/SQL: Item ignored
2/8      PLS-00201: identifier 'HR.EMPLOYEES' must be declared
5/1      PL/SQL: SQL Statement ignored
5/39     PL/SQL: ORA-00942: table or view does not exist
7/1      PL/SQL: Statement ignored
7/38     PLS-00320: the declaration of the type of this expression is
         incomplete or malformed
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will need to grant access to HR objects to user user1.

Connected as user HR:

```
grant select on employees to user1;
```

Comment: I have granted select to a role and assigned that role to user1

Comment: user1 can access the hr schema objects directly successsfully as follows. But cannot be accessed through a user created procedure                                    SQL> SELECT COUNT(*) FROM hr.employees;

  COUNT(*)
----------
       107

Comment: You need a direct grant in order to be able to access a table from a stored procedure, not through a role.

Comment: https://martincarstenbach.wordpress.com/2010/05/27/the-difference-between-a-direct-grant-and-a-role-in-plsql/

Answer (score 0):

You need to give a `select grant` of the `hr.employees` table **directly**.

From the HR user, you need to execute:

```
grant select on employees to user1;
```

Grant of `hr.employees` given to your user via **role** will not be considered when `PL/SQL` program(`procedure/function/etc..`) is executed with **definer's right**.

> The use of roles in a subprogram depends on whether it executes with
>   definer rights or invoker rights. Within a definer-rights subprogram,
>   all roles are disabled.

Find it in Oracle documentation [here](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/appdev.920/a96624/08_subs.htm#18575).

Cheers!!